# How to edit Server Side Files(checkout.php) in BigCommerce?

Tags: php, bigcommerce

The problem is that we have a store that serves customers in Europe and Netherlands  and at the billing details for Netherlands, if the VAT(Value Added  Tax) is not empty then we want the vat to be exempt in the bill. If it's empty or not, Right now it's by default included.

I see that if i put a conditional statement in checkout.php, the expected customization can be achieved.

So how to get access to the checkout.php?
Is there a way to do this through JavaScript, something like while billing details are filled then upon clicking submit then the form should be  submitted, before the submission,Can't we make the vat=0 (if it's Netherlands)

I hereby attach the image  [Billing Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sltO.png) .

Comment: Never ever do that using `Javascript` or any other client side code. People will modify it themselves to pay less.

Comment: @Kishor Thank you. So how can i get the access to the server side php file(checkout.php)?Is there a way through the Bigcommerce api?

Comment: There should be a way to do it directly without interfering with codes, I guess. Did you search enough?

Comment: @Kishor when i inspect element and try to figure out, I see that it's from checkout.php. I couldn't find anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can edit any of the server-side code directly since BigCommerce is a saas E-commerce platform. You get the flexibility to work with certain available API and 3rd party apps. Also, you can leverage stencil for customising your templates to a mo